# Resolving the router module to angular2 / electron app is failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I have an electron app written using Angular 2. I want to include the Router angular module.

My old package.json has these dependencies:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
     "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "jquery": "3.0.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  }
```

This worked fine but of course doesn't have the router. So i added the router using this line :

```
"@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
```

Which threw these messages:

```
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/common@2.0.0-rc.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0-rc.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1
├── @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1 
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser@2.0.0-rc.1
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.0.0-rc.1
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6

npm WARN @angular/forms@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/forms@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/router@3.1.2 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.1.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/upgrade@2.1.2 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@2.1.2 but none was installed.
```

So I changed my dev dependencies to the following:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
         "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
        "jquery": "3.0.0",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1"

  }
```

However after doing this I get he following warnings:

```
sudo npm install
npm WARN lifecycle star@1.0.0~postinstall: cannot run in wd %s %s (wd=%s) star@1.0.0 typings install /Users/asdd/Documents/Personal/Toolkit
star@1.0.0 /Users/asdd/Documents/Personal/Toolkit
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.1.2
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/http@2.1.2
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY rxjs@5.0.0-beta.12

npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.10 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1
```

I am not sure why -- this angular2-in-memory-web-api is not referenced in my package.json -- it used to be but I removed it because I am not sure what it is - and to my knowledge my application doesn't use it, but somehow its still showing up and causing dependency issues! My application also still fails to resolve the `import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';` line.

The entire dependencies list as it stands is as follows:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.34.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
         "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
        "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.10",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
        "jquery": "3.0.0",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
```

### }

This is star project's entire package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "star",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "blah blah blah",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --progress --profile --colors --display-error-details --display-cached",
    "start": "electron .",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "package-mac": "electron-packager . macapp --platform=mac --arch=x64",
    "package": "electron-packager . --all",
    "postinstall": "typings install"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "blah"
  ],
  "author": "coohoo",
  "license": "SEE LICENCE IN licence.txt",
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.5.0",
    "electron-prebuilt": "^1.2.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.34.0",
    "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
    "ts-loader": "^0.7.2",
    "typescript": "^1.7.3",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
  "@angular/common": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/core": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/http": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.1.2",
        "@angular/router": "2.0.0-rc.2",
        "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
        "reflect-metadata": "0.1.8",
        "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
        "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
        "jquery": "3.0.0",
        "xml2js": "^0.4.17"
  }
}
```

---

After removing the in memory api, I get the following error:

```
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.10 requires a peer of @angular/http@2.0.0-rc.1 but none was installed.
npm WARN angular2-in-memory-web-api@0.0.10 requires a peer of rxjs@5.0.0-beta.6 but none was installed.
```

The package.json is now as shown above.

Many thanks for any and all advice.

Comment: If you aren't using the In Memory Web API, you can remove that package.  The other dependency errors seem to be originating in this `star` package although I'm not sure where that's coming from (especially since it points to your local Documents folder).  Have you looked at it to make sure it's dependencies are valid/up to date?

Comment: Hey Dave, the star is my project's root folder.....everything is in this star, it is my application name - please see the entire package.json file for my application included above in the editted question.

Comment: Ahhh, I misread it...the 3 unmet dependencies are stemming from the In Memory API, you can delete that from the package.json if you aren't using it and the errors will go away.  Otherwise, you'll need to make sure it's updated to the version that uses the versions of Angular you have installed (which should be the version you listed in the full package.json)

Comment: Ok - so i removed it - and now i get the warnings as shown above.

Comment: Have you tried blowing away your node_modules folder and reinstalling?  Something seems hung up on having the API package installed, but I'm not seeing it in the package.json.  Also, in the full package.json you have the router version `rc.2` you'll need to update that to the latest version too

Comment: Ahh - good idea - ill try that!

Comment: Ok so now - I get no warnings *but* the application fails to load with error : 

Uncaught TypeError: platform_browser_dynamic_1.bootstrap is not a function

Comment: If you're updating from angular `rc.1` to any of the final versions, you may want to make sure you're bootstrapping everything correctly.  Double check what they show you in the quickstart.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127219/discussion-between-renegadeandy-and-dave-v).